# Check / uncheck components depending on installation type in Inno Setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I am creating an Inno Setup package that will install spelling dictionaries my application uses. Most people will only be installing one or a couple of dictionaries, so I have two installation types: Full and Custom. Each dictionary is a sub-component of a component named "Dictionaries". (There are over 20 dictionary files, I'm showing only two for brevity):

```
[Types]
Name: Full; Description: "Install ALL dictionaries";
Name: Custom; Description: "Select the dictionaries to install"; Flags: IsCustom;

[Components]
Name: Dictionaries; Description: "Spelling dictionaries"; Types: Full;
Name: Dictionaries\EnUK; Description: "English (UK)"; Types: Full;
Name: Dictionaries\EnUS; Description: "English (US)"; Types: Full;

[Files]
Source: "E:\path\English (UK).adm"; DestDir: {app}; Components: Dictionaries\EnUK
Source: "E:\path\English (US).adm"; DestDir: {app}; Components: Dictionaries\EnUS
```

What I want to achieve:

- When user selects "Full", installer should automatically check all dictionaries.
- When user selects "Custom", installer should **deselect** all dictionaries.

Instead, *all* dictionaries are initially selected in the Full mode, and they remain selected  when user picks the Custom mode. I expected them to become automatically deselected in the latter case, since the Custom type is not listed for any of the components.

The strange thing is, if I insert another installation type between the two, e.g. "English only", in which only English dictionaries are included, then the installer does automatically uncheck the 20 other files on selecting this type. But it still refuses to uncheck them when the Custom type is selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not strange at all; it is simply how the 'Custom' type works. Indeed, this is a very special type, due to the flag `IsCustom`. If you select this type, the installer will make no automatic changes, since, by definition, the custom type is supposed to let the user choose everything manually. You could create a new type called 'Typical' or 'Minimal' that only installs the English dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by Andreas Rejbrand is correct. However, there is a workaround available to programmatically disable custom components. See [How to allow to only install specific components in InnoSetup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283508/how-to-allow-to-only-install-specific-components-in-innosetup)