# Inno Setup - Check if a component is installed

Tags: inno-setup, pascal, pascalscript

What I really want to do is have Inno Setup uninstall a component, if it's unchecked in a subsequent run. But, if I'm not mistaken, that is not possible in Inno Setup (actually, correct me, if I'm wrong on this).

So, instead I want to make check function to see if a component is installed, so I can hide it during subsequent runs. I'm not sure where else to get that info other than the `Inno Setup: Selected Components` under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\[AppName]_is1`.

Now the problem is my `Inno Setup: Selected Components` is `as,as2,as3,bs,bs2,bs3`.
How can I detect `as`, without detecting `as2` or `as3`?

Comment: See also [Inno Setup: Disable already installed components on upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35454876/850848).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, Inno Setup does not support uninstalling components.

---

For a similar question (and maybe better), see:
[Inno Setup: Disable already installed components on upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35454876/850848)

---

For checking of installed components, I'd rather suggest you to check for existence of files corresponding to the component.

---

Anyway, to answer your actual question: If you want to scan the `Inno Setup: Selected Components` entry, you can use this function:

```pascal
function ItemExistsInList(Item: string; List: string): Boolean;
var
  S: string;
  P: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  while (not Result) and (List <> '') do
  begin
    P := Pos(',', List);
    if P > 0 then
    begin
      S := Copy(List, 1, P - 1);
      Delete(List, 1, P);
    end
      else
    begin
      S := List;
      List := '';
    end;

    Result := (CompareText(S, Item) = 0);
  end;
end;
```

Note that the uninstall key can be present in `HKCU` (not in `HKLM`) under certain circumstances.

Comment: OK, this works, but I'm not gonna be using this. I misunderstood what inno does to `Inno Setup: Selected Components`. I thought it would ADD the components to the value, but it actually replaces the entire value, which renders this whole process useless. I'll take a look at the solution in the post you linked, but I guess I'll end up checking for installed files, as you suggested.

Comment: Actually, that post says the same thing. `Inno Setup: Selected Components` is being rewritten during each install, so it's kinda useless for porposes like this. File check it is, then...

Comment: If you just disable the already installed component (and keep it checked), you will have all components in the `Inno Setup: Selected Components`.

Comment: I applied the check functions on the components, the result is `true`, so those components are not visible on second run, and they are unchecked by default (since Inno sees them as already installed).